# how to return cons in a function react native?

Tags: reactjs, native

I need to return a const in a function. this is my code:

```
ValidarSections(){
    if(global.titulo === "Telefonia - Implementaciones"){
      return  SECTIONS = [
        {
          title: "Milestone",
          content: this.state.Milestone
        }
      ]
    }

    if(global.titulo === "Telefonia - Integraciones"){
      return SECTIONS = [
        {
          title: "Relevamiento",
          content: this.state.RelevamientoINT
        },
        {
          title: "Instalaciones",
          content: this.state.Instalaciones
        },
        {
          title: "Integraciones",
          content: this.state.Integracion
        }
      ]
    }

    if(global.titulo === "Obras Civiles"){
      return SECTIONS = [
        {
          title: "Obra",
          content: this.state.Obra
        },
        {
          title: "Relevamiento",
          content: this.state.RelevamientoOBR
        }
      ]
    }
  }


  render() {
    const SECTIONS = this.ValidarSections()
    ....
   }
```

to be able to use this const in the library Accordion.
I am new to react native as I can do it?

Comment: What is your problem ? maybe you are just missing a default case ? there is an example on the github : https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

Comment: if I put the SECTIONS in the render () like that: 
```
render () {
const SECTIONS = [
       {
         title: "Milestone",
         content: this.state.Milestone
       }
     ]
...
```
it works but when I do it with the function it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return a constant, you return a value. Remove `SECTIONS =` from your return statement:

```
ValidarSections(){
    if(global.titulo === "Telefonia - Implementaciones"){
      return [
        {
          title: "Milestone",
          content: this.state.Milestone
        }
      ]
    }

    if(global.titulo === "Telefonia - Integraciones"){
      return [
        {
          title: "Relevamiento",
          content: this.state.RelevamientoINT
        },
        {
          title: "Instalaciones",
          content: this.state.Instalaciones
        },
        {
          title: "Integraciones",
          content: this.state.Integracion
        }
      ]
    }

    if(global.titulo === "Obras Civiles"){
      return [
        {
          title: "Obra",
          content: this.state.Obra
        },
        {
          title: "Relevamiento",
          content: this.state.RelevamientoOBR
        }
      ]
    }
  }


  render() {
    const SECTIONS = this.ValidarSections()
    ....
   }
```